# Run one node in another node?

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The subject looks weird and difficult to understand so I am going to explain what I mean here. I want to know if it is possible to run a node inside another node. For example, when you have written a ROS node A and what you want A to do is to run other several ROS nodes B, C, D and etc. How to implement that? I don't want to use roslaunch to run several nodes in this case because after node A has run other nodes, it also has to do other stuff.

To go further, I want to write a ROS server and what it is supposed to do is waiting for "node request", that is , when a client calls this service, the server tries to run a node instantaneously.  That is to say, how to run nodes in a service server? I think this case is essentially the same as the former one.

Any suggestions are appreciated very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220452/run-one-node-in-another-node?/) by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2015-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How about using nodelets? You can load multiple nodelets in a node at runtime and each nodelet runs in it's own thread.

http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet

---

Originally posted by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) with karma: 789 on 2015-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2017-04-21**:
Thank you. Could you provide with me some sample codes?